# Discord.js reply to multiple words with cooldown and random answer between choosen words

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm currently working on a bot that replies on the word `"frog"` and `"yarr"` with `"Word1"` or `"Word2"` (50%/50% chance with cooldown included).

```js
const rG = ["Word1", "Word2"]
const randomMessage = rG[Math.floor(Math.random() * rG.length)];
let myFrog = /frog/i;
let myYarr = /yarr/i;
client.on("message", message => {
if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (
    myYarr.test(message.content) ||
    myFrog.test(message.content)
    ) 
    if (userCooldown[message.author.id]) return;
    userCooldown[message.author.id] = true;
    message.reply(randomMessage);
    setTimeout(() => {
      userCooldown[message.author.id] = false;
    }, 5000); //5 sec cooldown
})
```

The problem is that it doesn't matter what the user sends, it just replies and skips the cooldown too. Plus somehow it's not random for some reason, it depends if I change the first number of the cooldown, but no idea how it is connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you indent your code properly, you can see that the only line inside your first if statement is `if (userCooldown[message.author.id]) return`. The rest of the code runs regardless of your `test`s:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (myYarr.test(message.content) || myFrog.test(message.content))
    if (userCooldown[message.author.id]) return;

  // => it's outside of the myYarr.tests
  userCooldown[message.author.id] = true;
  message.reply(randomMessage);
  setTimeout(() => {
    userCooldown[message.author.id] = false;
  }, 5000); //5 sec cooldown
});
```

You need to make sure that you use curly braces (`{}`) if you only want to execute the rest of your code when one of the regex tests are true.

Also, you could probably create a new array with the words you're expecting and check if the user-submitted message is one of these words. You can use [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) for this. This way it's easier to add new words and you only need to update your code on a single line.

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  const replies = ['Word1', 'Word2'];
  const randomMessage = replies[Math.floor(Math.random() * replies.length)];
  const wordList = ['frog', 'yarr'];

  if (wordList.includes(message.content.toLowerCase())) {
    if (userCooldown[message.author.id])
      return;

    userCooldown[message.author.id] = true;
    message.reply(randomMessage);

    setTimeout(() => {
      userCooldown[message.author.id] = false;
    }, 5000);
  }
});
```

Comment: everything works fine until the random part. The number's somehow connect. The output is not random, somehow the "5000" (The Cooldown) is contributing to what will be the output. So when i change the first number of the Cooldown the output will change also in a Guaranteed way. anyway to fix this?

Comment: Not sure if I can understand what you mean but if you just move everything inside the callback function, it will generate a new random reply every time someone sends a message. I've just updated my answer above.

Comment: Fixed it, I just replaced the const with var where it says ```const randomMessage = replies[Math.floor(Math.random() * replies.length)]``` and placed between the line of userCooldown and message.reply so when I run the command it changes